amp-sticky-ad is not 100px high (padding eats 4 pixels)
amp-sticky-ad is supposed to be 100px high. At the same time, there is a padding element <amp-sticky-ad-top-padding class="amp-sticky-ad-top-padding"></amp-sticky-ad-top-padding> just above tha ad, that creates extra 4px padding, leaving just 96px for the ad itself. As a result, ads that are 100px high are missing 4px on the bottom.
Is this a bug in amp-sticky-ad, or am I missign something? Tried searching configurable options of amp-sticky-ad, did not find anything related.

